# A possible analogy between two setups used with Special Relativity time evaluation

Tags: classical-mechanics

Trying to understand  Special Relativity . I am currently reading  the book of David Morin, “Special Relativity”.
 In order to demonstrate one of the consequences of the relativity postulate , the length contraction, the author bases his discussion on the much used moving platform model  (ch. 11) and describe the corresponding kinematics, as follows:

*"Consider the following setup (I). Person A stands on a train which he measures to have length
L . The train moves at speed v with respect to the ground. A light source is located at the back of the train, and a mirror is located at the front. The source emits a flash of light which heads to the mirror, bounces of it and  then heads
back to the source. By looking at how long this process takes in the two reference frames,
we can determine the length of the train as measured by B..
In A's frame  the round-trip time for the light is 
                          Ta =2L/c     (I) "*

On the other hand, in many presentations of the Michelson-Morley experiment (II) , (see for instance “Feynman Lectures” Vol.1,par.15.3), the light round-trip duration Tb for the arm parallel to the hypothetical  movement of earth in “ether”,is evaluated as:

```
                 Tb = 2Lc/(c**2- v**2)     (II)
```

Now, in my understanding ( read it “not understanding” !) , with Michelson-Morley montage in (II) imagined  on a moving platform as in (I), the two setups (I) , (II) above , are analog. The observers in (I) resp. (II), are at rest with respect to their respective moving “platforms” . In both setups (I), (II), the times are evaluated from the relative speed between the light and the platforms.

With these in mind, I can’t understand the difference between Ta and Tb expressions in eq. (I) resp.(II), above.
These expressions differ,only   being identical only for the special case of v = 0.

As nobody will put in doubt the SR  knowledge,  of people like  David Morin   ( a PhD in theoretical particle physics from Harvard University, currently a lecturer at Harvard), it is for me to accept that the analogy I suppose to exist between the two setups, simply doesn’t exist ! 
Could then someone, help me see, where the difference between the two setups (I) and (II), is coming from ?

Thanks !
Puccini

Answer (score 0):

The $T_b$ Michelson Morley expression is calculated *assuming* that light is a wave in a medium and if the medium is moving with speed $v$  then light travels with speed $c+v$ and $c-v$ along the two legs. Persons A and B on the train and platform assume that light always travels with speed $c$. So the basic difference is that $T_a$ is right (person $B$ will measure $\gamma T_a$ but that's right too) and $T_b$ is wrong. Which is what the null result of Michelson-Morley shows.